# Integral of $\int \frac{\sin^22x}{\cos2x}\,\mathrm dx.$

Tags: integration

I would like to solve the following integral

> $$\int \frac{\sin^22x}{\cos2x}\,\mathrm dx.$$
>   I know that the derivative of $\cos$ its $\sin$ but how its help me?
>   Any suggestions? 
>   
>   Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\int \frac{\sin^2 2x}{\cos 2x}~dx ~ = ~ \int \sec 2x - \cos 2x~dx ~ = ~ \frac{1}{2} \int \sec u - \cos u ~ du \quad (u = 2x)$$